# Fill gaps in time intervals with other time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

We have two tables with time intervals. I want to fill gaps in `df1` with `df2` as in the graph to get `df3`. `df1` is moved to `df3` as it is, and only the parts of `df2` that lie in the gaps of `df1` (difference) are moved to `df3`.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQeML.png]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-15', '2023-04-18', '2023-05-15', '2023-05-25'],
                    'End': ['2023-01-15', '2023-02-20', '2023-04-01', '2023-05-03',  '2023-05-20', '2023-05-30']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-20', '2023-02-25', '2023-03-05', '2023-04-18', '2023-05-12'],
                    'End': ['2023-01-03', '2023-01-10', '2023-02-10', '2023-03-01', '2023-04-15', '2023-05-10', '2023-06-05']})

df3 =  pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-20', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-25', '2023-03-05', '2023-03-15', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-18', '2023-05-04', '2023-05-12', '2023-05-15', '2023-05-21', '2023-05-25', '2023-05-31'],
                     'End': ['2023-01-15', '2023-01-31', '2023-02-20', '2023-03-01', '2023-03-14', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-15', '2023-05-03', '2023-05-10', '2023-05-14', '2023-05-20', '2023-05-24', '2023-05-30', '2023-06-05']})

# df1

        Start         End
0  2023-01-01  2023-01-15
1  2023-02-01  2023-02-20
2  2023-03-15  2023-04-01
3  2023-04-18  2023-05-03
4  2023-05-15  2023-05-20
5  2023-05-25  2023-05-30

# df2

        Start         End
0  2023-01-02  2023-01-03
1  2023-01-05  2023-01-10
2  2023-01-20  2023-02-10
3  2023-02-25  2023-03-01
4  2023-03-05  2023-04-15
5  2023-04-18  2023-05-10
6  2023-05-12  2023-06-05

# df3 (desired result)

         Start         End
0   2023-01-01  2023-01-15
1   2023-01-20  2023-01-31
2   2023-02-01  2023-02-20
3   2023-02-25  2023-03-01
4   2023-03-05  2023-03-14
5   2023-03-15  2023-04-01
6   2023-04-02  2023-04-15
7   2023-04-18  2023-05-03
8   2023-05-04  2023-05-10
9   2023-05-12  2023-05-14
10  2023-05-15  2023-05-20
11  2023-05-21  2023-05-24
12  2023-05-25  2023-05-30
13  2023-05-31  2023-06-05
```

Code to generate plot:

```
import plotly.express as px

df_plot = pd.concat(
    [
        df1.assign(color='df1', df='df1'),
        df2.assign(color='df2', df='df2'), 
        df3.assign(color=['df1', 'df2', 'df1', 'df2', 'df2', 'df1', 'df2', 'df1', 'df2', 'df2', 'df1', 'df2', 'df1', 'df2'], df='df3')
    ],
)
fig = px.timeline(df_plot, x_start="Start", x_end="End", y="df", color="color")
fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='category descending')
fig.show()
```

Comment: So, if the first or second interval of df2 wouldn't exist, would you split the first interval of df1? or not?

Comment: df1 is the main dataframe and should be moved to df3 as it is. Only the gaps in df1 should be filled with df2.

Comment: I see, this wasn't obvious.

Comment: Can you provide the code to generate the plot?

Answer (score 3):

I think I can get you close:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-15'],
                    'End': ['2023-01-15', '2023-02-20', '2023-04-01']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-20', '2023-02-25', '2023-03-05'],
                    'End': ['2023-01-03', '2023-01-10', '2023-02-10', '2023-03-01', '2023-04-15']})
df3 =  pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-20', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-25', '2023-03-05', '2023-03-15', '2023-04-02'],
                     'End': ['2023-01-15', '2023-01-31', '2023-02-20', '2023-03-01', '2023-03-14', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-15']})


df1['dates'] = [pd.date_range(s,e) for s, e in zip(df1['Start'], df1['End'])]    
df2['dates'] = [pd.date_range(s,e) for s, e in zip(df2['Start'], df2['End'])]

df1e = df1.explode('dates').assign(source='df1')
df2e = df2.explode('dates').assign(source='df2')


df3e = df1e.set_index(df1e['dates']).combine_first(df2e.set_index(df2e['dates']))
df3e['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df3e['dates'])

df3e['group'] = ((df3e['source'] != df3e['source'].shift()) | 
                 (df3e['dates'] - df3e['dates'].shift() > pd.Timedelta(days=1))).cumsum()

df_out = df3e.groupby(['group', 'source'])['dates'].agg([min, max])
```

Output:

```
                    min        max
group source                      
1     df1    2023-01-01 2023-01-15
2     df2    2023-01-20 2023-01-31
3     df1    2023-02-01 2023-02-20
4     df2    2023-02-25 2023-03-01
5     df2    2023-03-05 2023-03-14
6     df1    2023-03-15 2023-04-01
7     df2    2023-04-02 2023-04-15
```

Graphical Output:

```
import plotly.express as px

df_out = df_out.reset_index().rename({'source':'color', 'min':'Start', 'max':'End'}, axis=1)
df_plot = pd.concat(
    [
        df1.assign(color='df1'),
        df2.assign(color='df2'), 
        df_out
    ],
    keys=['df1' , 'df2', 'df3']
).reset_index(level=0, names='df')
fig = px.timeline(df_plot, x_start="Start", x_end="End", y="df", color="color")
fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='category descending')
fig.show()
```

Graph:

[image]

with updated dataset:

```
                    min        max
group source                      
1     df1    2023-01-01 2023-01-15
2     df2    2023-01-20 2023-01-31
3     df1    2023-02-01 2023-02-20
4     df2    2023-02-25 2023-03-01
5     df2    2023-03-05 2023-03-14
6     df1    2023-03-15 2023-04-01
7     df2    2023-04-02 2023-04-15
8     df1    2023-04-18 2023-05-03
9     df2    2023-05-04 2023-05-10
10    df2    2023-05-12 2023-05-14
11    df1    2023-05-15 2023-05-20
12    df2    2023-05-21 2023-05-24
13    df1    2023-05-25 2023-05-30
14    df2    2023-05-31 2023-06-05
```

Graph output:

[image]

Comment: I see am missing that red group that does back to back with a break in time.  I need to add a time diff condition in the grouping.

Comment: it's actually not so easy, consider for example 3 blue intervals in the last red interval, you'd need to generate 4 red intervals ;)

Comment: @mozway I think there is some logic that can handle this situtation.   Yeah not easy, but I think I've given Mykola a path to complete.

Comment: Fair enough, then I also have such a solution, I have an idea for the complete solution but I need to find a moment to test/write it ;)

Comment: @MykolaZotko  see update, this should get you pretty close..

Comment: Added date diff time element to grouping

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you for your answer. As this method uses the `date_range`, it can be very resource intensive if we are dealing with large datasets or timestamps with hours and minutes.

Comment: @MykolaZotko Yeah... I played with an idea of using pd.IntervalIndex, however, I couldn't quite figure out how to handle the last situation of splitting d2 with multiple d1 intervals.  I think there maybe a python library that does intervals.

Answer (score 2):

Full vectorial solution:

```
tmp = (pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['ref', 'other']).rename_axis(index=['origin', 'index'])
         .sort_values(by=['Start', 'End']).astype('datetime64').reset_index()
         .assign(ref_next_start=lambda d: d['Start'].where(d['origin']=='ref').bfill(),
                 ref_prev_end=lambda d: d['End'].where(d['origin']=='ref').ffill(),
                 other_prev_end=lambda d: d['End'].where(d['origin']=='other').ffill(),
                )
      )

m = tmp['origin'].eq('ref')

out = pd.concat(
          [(tmp.loc[tmp['End'].ge(tmp['ref_prev_end'])]
               .assign(End=lambda d: d['End'].mask(d['origin'].shift(-1).eq('ref'),
                                                   d['ref_next_start']-pd.Timedelta("1d")))
           )[['origin', 'Start', 'End']],
           (tmp.loc[m & tmp['End'].le(tmp['other_prev_end']), ['End', 'other_prev_end']]
               .rename(columns={'End': 'Start', 'other_prev_end': 'End'})
               .assign(Start=lambda d: d['Start']+pd.Timedelta("1d"), origin='other')
            )]
).sort_values(by=['Start', 'End'], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  origin      Start        End
0    ref 2023-01-01 2023-01-15
1  other 2023-01-20 2023-01-31
2    ref 2023-02-01 2023-02-20
3  other 2023-02-25 2023-03-01
4  other 2023-03-05 2023-03-14
5    ref 2023-03-15 2023-04-01
6  other 2023-04-02 2023-04-15
```

Previous temporary solution that also doesn't compute the last interval, it should be relatively efficient:

```
tmp = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1', 'df2'], names=['origin']).reset_index(level=0)

tmp['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp['Start'])
tmp['End'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp['End'])

out = (tmp
 .sort_values(by=['Start', 'End'], ignore_index=True)
 .assign(m=lambda d: d['origin'].eq('df1'),
         Start=lambda d: d['Start'].mask((~d['m']) & d['Start'].lt(s:=d['End'].where(out['m']).ffill()), s.add(pd.Timedelta('1day'))),
         End=lambda d: d['End'].mask((~d['m']) & d['End'].gt(s:=d['Start'].where(out['m']).bfill()), s.sub(pd.Timedelta('1day'))),
        )
  .query('Start<End').drop(columns='m')
)
```

Output:

```
  origin      Start        End
0    df1 2023-01-01 2023-01-15
3    df2 2023-01-20 2023-01-31
4    df1 2023-02-01 2023-02-20
5    df2 2023-02-25 2023-03-01
6    df2 2023-03-05 2023-03-14
7    df1 2023-03-15 2023-04-01
```

Comment: @Scott don't know yet, no time to test now, I'll try to benchmark later

Comment: Thank you very much! It doesn't solve all cases, e.g. when the interval of `df2` encloses 2 intervals of `df1`, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: @MykolaZotko can you update your example with such a case?